# IntelliJ does Not Display Errors in the Project Window

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

I am using the Eclipse compiler and have enabled 'Build Project Automatically'. I am not using the power saver mode as well.

This should be a trivial thing to solve for IDEA, but for some reason, they decided that they shouldn't. Suppose I have a class `A` that uses a field from class `B`. Now if I make a syntax error in `B`, it highlights that class in the project windows. But if I delete the field that is being used in class `A`, no highlighting is done in class `A`, until I actually open it.

Eclipse does it so well. Am I missing something or is this feature really not present in IntelliJ?

Comment: Please check that "Save files automatically" option is enabled in "Settings /Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings"